# Unable to RDP the AZURE VM

Tags: powershell, azure, virtual-machine

We have restarted the Azure VM in safemode with Networking, unfortutanely connection has been lost to the server and we are not able to connect the server through RDP.

Is there any ways to establish connection to the VM by reseting windows firewall abd RDP registry values. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I doubt Terminal Services can run in safe-mode.

Comment: Why safemode? If you restart the VM again, it should come back up normally and then you could RDP into it.

Comment: We had changed the boot settings to Safemode with Networking using MSCONFIG. We booted it in safe mode for application dependency as per vendor.

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect to the VM via remote PowerShell. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/tutorial-manage-vm#connect-to-vm).